# Lançando exceções no Eloquent ORM Observers

Tags: php, laravel, exceção, laravel-eloquent

Tenho o seguinte código no meu model:

```
public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();

    // Não deixa excluir caso possua registros vinculados.
    static::deleting(function($content_area){
        if($total = $content_area->contents->count() > 0){
            //throw new Exception("Essa área não pode ser removida, ela possui {$total} conteútos vinculados.");
            return App::abort(403, "Essa área não pode ser removida, ela possui {$total} conteútos vinculados.");
        }
    });
}
```

No meu controller tenho o seguinte:

```
public function destroy($id){
    $content_area = ContentArea::find($id);

    try {
        $content_area->delete();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return Response::json(
            [
                'success' => 'false',
                'message' => $e->getMessage(),
                'messageType' => 'error'
            ]
        );
    }

    return Response::json(['success' => false]);
}
```

Teoricamente, durante a exclusão do registro, ele deveria lançar a exceção, caso a condição for verdadeira dentro do observer.

O Problema é que ele mostra a tela de exceções do Laravel e mata a aplicação. Eu não queria que acontecesse isso, queria que ele apenas retornasse a mensagem para eu exibir ao usuário. Alguém sabe por que isso está acontecendo?

Answer (score 2):

Se você está usando namespaces, é bem provável que precise informar ao PHP que a tua exceção não está no namespace atual e sim no raiz:

```
catch (\Exception $e)
```

Comment: O "catch" dele esta dentro do controller, portanto não seria necessário utilizar o namespace apontando para raiz. Falo isso porque estou com o mesmo problema. Criei um observer e tento dar `throw new Exception` mas o controller não pega a exception.

Comment: Estando dentro do controller não faz diferença, se o controller está dentro de um namespace, todas as referências a classes dentro deste controller serão, por padrão, direcionadas ao mesmo namespace dele, a menos que o programador indique um novo namespace, no caso o raiz (\\). Criei um gist para testar e mostrar isso funcionando: https://gist.github.com/antonioribeiro/7d4feb011b2e61599544. Se adicionar a barra (\\) ao primeiro catch ele passa a capturar a exceção naquele ponto.